# How to edit/remove hidden section in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google Doc where it has two hidden sections, "Issued by" and "Representative". Their headers are visible in the automatically-generated table of contents. However, the sections themselves are hidden and don't even show in the document outline nor print preview. But, after downloading the file, the hidden content shows up in the preview.

[image: Hidden section in table of content]

How can I edit or remove the headings in the ToC?

Note: I think it was done with PandaDoc (an add on). But, even after opening the file with PandaDoc I still couldn't see the hidden <s>files</s> texts.

Comment: can you share a copy of your doc?

Comment: Have you refreshed the table of contents? Do you know how to refresh the table of contents? (Click the circular arrow to the left of it.)

Comment: I think you made a mistake when you said "I can't see the hidden _files_".

Comment: @Sahab I just want to check what you mean by "After downloading the file, the hidden content shows up in the preview." Does that mean the body text of these sections appear in the _print_ preview, after you download the file as a MS Word document? (I'm not sure why you need to download the file in the first place.)

Comment: @user0  here is the link for the document. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B_m64b-I9pF6b4ElTaFb7xE5_LnE2sZU92o46VREP4E

Comment: @ahorn. Yes I tried refreshing the table of content. but those section won't disappear. 

Yes, I meant texts instead of files. That was a mistake.

Comment: @ahorn what I meant by "after downloading the file...." . Yes the body text of these section appear in print preview and Thumbnails.  I downloaded them as  PDF not as  MS Word document. I was just testing where the texts shows up.

Comment: @Sahab there is no body text in that Doc, and when I download the PDF, no hidden body text becomes visible either.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't appear in the outline is a clue, since the "ISSUED BY" and "REPRESENTATIVE" come up as second-level headings in the ToC, but not in the outline, yet _all_ other headings that are created appear in the outline.   ...some possibly irrelevant information: pressing ctrl + F indeed finds _two_ entries for "ISSUED BY" and "REPRESENTATIVE" respectively, yet the second finding in each case is hidden. It's possible to replace the words.

Comment: I can't solve this, so I'll leave this question. Take my upvote.